# Why is it (probably) a bad idea to process database data with programming languages like C / Python?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I'm working on a task of calculating medians for every 100 records in a giant MySQL table, which appears to be a straightforward problem but ends up with very complex SQL code. One of my friend who saw my work asked me, why don't you load the data into memory and process it with C or Python, wouldn't that be easier? My intuition is that it is a bad idea. But can someone elaborate more about why it is not suggested? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes you should do your heavy lifting in the database. If your dataset is fairly small, it wouldn't matter whether you do the calculations on the database server or on the database client.

The primary consideration whether to do the calculation in the db server vs on the db client is usually of performance. If you do the heavy calculations on the db client, you may end up having to transfer a lot of data through the db connection. With large datasets, transferring the entire table to the client may become performance issues, and if your database server lives in a different machine than your application server (i.e. not localhost), then the network transfer overhead becomes even worse.

If you have to transfer the entire dataset anyway, then there likely won't be any significant performance difference. The SQL language itself isn't inherently faster than the client languages for doing number crunching, it simply has the advantage of running on the server process and thus can avoid the overhead of data transfer.

There are also applications that uses multiple data sources, for these, generally you'll will often up with no other choice but to do parts your calculations the client side.

Ultimately, you have to measure. It didn't matter whether it's best practice or not, if doing the calculation in the client is fast enough and it simplify the overall code doing that, then do take that route.

Comment: Quite thorough explanation. The overhead should be more of a problem in the case of separate machines. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can think of no good reason to tell you that it's a bad idea to use a front-end to process data stored in a MySQL db... to me it's something like "don't use knives to cut your food because you can cut your own finger".

You can, of course write some stored procedures or functions that might give you the results you need, but if you can't make it work with MySQL, then the obvious step is to use another tool.

You must, however, take some precautions:

1. Don't overload your network connection (trivial if you are working on localhost).
2. Don't try to store too big resultsets in memory: keep it simple and small (divide and conquer)
3. Let the database server do the heavy work, and use your front-end to do the fine work (if you need to filter data, let MySQL do that for you, and write the code to do the calculations on the filtered data).
4. Be sure to take the appropriate precautions when sending queries to MySQL (avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities)

Comment: But shouldn't there be significant performance differences between using SQL and other tools? As SQL is really not convenient in many cases, I guess it must has its own reason to exist.

Comment: There's no free lunch, of course... but, as I said, if you can't make it work with MySQL, then you need another tool. Try to write the stored procedures (if your calculations aren't too complex, that may be faster). If you can't make it work with stored procedures, why shouldn't you try something else?

Comment: Yeah it's indeed better to measure according to the situations than stick to one as "best practice". And thanks for the tips on precaution!